# python3 nested dictionary unpack for format string

Tags: python-3.x, format, unpack

I am trying to pass a dictionary (loaded from JSON file) to format string. While single key-value **unpack** works correctly, I am not sure how I can access the **nested keys** (children) with a format string.

Or is there any other better way to pass JSON to string format?

```
config = {
    "TEST": "TEST",
    "TEST1": "TEST1",
    "TEST2": {
        "TEST21": "TEST21"
    }
}

query_1 = """
    {TEST} {TEST1}
"""
query_2 = """
    {TEST} {TEST1}
    {TEST2.TEST21}
"""

print(query_1.format( **config ))  # WORKING
print(query_2.format( **config ))  # NOT WORKING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using f-string

```
config = {
    "TEST": "TEST",
    "TEST1": "TEST1",
    "TEST2": {
        "TEST21": "TEST21"
    }
}

query_2 = f"""
    {config['TEST']} {config['TEST1']}
    {config['TEST2']['TEST21']}
"""

print(query_2)
```

Note, if query is sql query, there is probably better way to do what you do, not using string formatting

Comment: Thank you for your nice suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

In your `query_2` change `{TEST2.TEST21}` to `{TEST2[TEST21]}` it will work.

Ex.

```
query_2 = """
    {TEST} {TEST1}
    {TEST2[TEST21]}
"""
print(query_2.format(**config))
```

**Output**

```
TEST TEST1
TEST21
```